# Counting number of links for each row and adding the counts as a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count the 'href' instances within the 'Body' column and add the count value as a new column corresponding for each row.

I can get the count of links using this:

```
dataframe1['Body'].str.contains('href').sum()
```

However, this finds the link count for all rows not per row, which is 1770. I tried the following, it assigned again the link count for all rows (i.e., 1770). So, it also did not work:

```
dataframe1['LinkCount'] = dataframe1['Body'].str.contains('href').sum()
```

I thought, `apply()` would work, but it returned NaN value as the count value:

```
dataframe1['LinkCount'] = dataframe1[['Body']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('href').sum())
```

Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `apply` is the way to go. However, without having data to test on I can only guess: In your lambda, try `x.Body...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [134]: df
Out[134]:
                              Body
0                              aaa
1                      href...href
2                              bbb
3                             href
4  href aaa href bbb href ccc href

In [135]: df['count'] = df.Body.str.findall('href').apply(len)

In [136]: df
Out[136]:
                              Body  count
0                              aaa      0
1                      href...href      2
2                              bbb      0
3                             href      1
4  href aaa href bbb href ccc href      4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> import pandas as pd
> df = pd.DataFrame([["AAAAAAAA"], ["AAABBB"]], columns=['body'])
> df['count'] = df.apply(lambda r: r.body.count('A'), axis=1)
# df['count'] = df.body.count('A') # (better) alternative, as in the answer of MaxU
> df
       body  count
0  AAAAAAAA      8
1    AAABBB      3
```

This should also work for multi-line strings, but does not respect HTML formatting, escaping, comments and so on. Of course, you have to adapt `r.body.count('A')` to your needs. But I suppose, `r.body.str.contains('href').sum()` should work out straight-forward.